# External login with AspNet Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-web-api2

im trying to do external login with Google using Aspnet.

I created an mvc/webapi project with individual user accounts (vs2013). This will create some files like the 'AccountController' which contains `GetExternalLogins` action, after calling this action I get (because the google external login is set in the 'Startup' class) an object like this :

```
{
    name: "Google",
    state: null,
    url: "/api/Account/ExternalLogin?provider=Google&response_type=token&client_id=self&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A11166%2F"
}
```

**The problem now** : when i do another http request to "/api/Account/ExternalLogin?provider=Google&response_type=token&client_id=self&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A11166%2F" I get the following error :

*XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=my_client_id_here. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:11166' is therefore not allowed access*

Im i doing something wrong ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that its a silly question 5 seconds after posting it.

No need to do an http request, a simple redirection to the url works.